# how can I change value of globally declared variable in c#

Tags: c#

```
    public  int a;

    public void currentvalue(int a)
    {
        if (a == 5)
        {
            a = 10;
            Console.WriteLine("a" + a);
        }
    }
```

how can I change the value of a into 10

Comment: first I declare variable a like this

public int a;

Comment: Use the `this` keyword

Comment: Maybe... don't name your variables and params with useless letters? Use meaningful naming.

Comment: thank you sigge. Can you explain how it will achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have both a global variable (field) and a local variable (parameter/local) with the same name in the same scope, the compiler will automatically choose the locally declared variable.

When dealing with a non-static (instance referenced) field, you can still access the field by using the `this` keyword. Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int number = 2;

    public void Calc(int number) //when number: 4
    {
        int result1 = number * 3;       //result1: 12
        int result2 =  this.number * 3; //result2: 6
    }
}
```

If your globally declared variable is static, you can't use `this` (which is only usable on instance references). In that case, use a type reference instead:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static int number = 2;

    public void Calc(int number) //when number: 4
    {
        int result1 = number * 3;         //result1: 12
        int result2 = MyClass.number * 3; //result2: 6
    }
}
```

You may want to read up on the `this` keyword [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this).

Comment: Thanks sigge. I got the expected answer with explanation in your post

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ref keyword and pass the reference into function :

```
    public void currentvalue(ref int a)
    {
        if (a == 5)
        {
            a = 10;
            Console.WriteLine("a" + a);
        }
    }
```